# How to use non-repeatable HttpEntity with authentication challenges?

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpclient-4.x, bearer-token

I'm building a client that basically needs to send and retrieve files as `InputStream` (it has to be) from an endpoint that requires authentication.

I'm using Apache `HttpClient` with a `Bearer` `AuthScheme` I created that handles our own flow of token retrieval using a specific cahce for the tokens, something around the lines of:

```
@Override
public String getToken(Credentials credentials, HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) {
    return tokenProvider.getToken(getParameters(),
            request.getRequestLine().getMethod(),
            request.getRequestLine().getUri());
}
```

Where the `TokenProvider` is expected to go out with it's own request to get tokens for me from a third party service.

Now, I create my requests using `InputStreamEntity` which is non-repeatable and therefore will fail the second time the request goes out, the flow being:

1. First request goes out and fails with 404
2. The `AuthSchem` is triggered retrieveing the required token based on the challenge
3. The client redoes the request, where it fails with a `NonRepeatableRequestException`

I know I can use a `Repeatable` entity and be done with it but we're talking about very (very) large files potentially, I can't simply buffer them into memory.

I also tried using a `HttpRequestInterceptor` to preemptively do the first request and populate the token cache based on the challenge it gets but this is a really ugly flow in my opinion, also the token is retrieved based on the challenge which the current request is about to get.

I also tried using Jets3t's `RepeatableRequestEntity` which does the trick but I prefer not to include dependencies where they are not really needed and I have not throughly tested its performance.

So my question is:  how is everybody else doing this? it's not just limited to `Bearer` authentication - how do you handle sending `InputStream` over the wire where challenge-based authentication is required?